# Removing the onion layers in an intact way without cooking them

Tags: onions

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the onion layers in an intact way so they're not broken or damaged. I've done this before by slightly baking the onion until it softens

Comment: Could you say why you're attempting to do this?  There might be different suggestions based on what the end goal is.  (eg, the mention of making a bowl)

Comment: @Joe - I'm trying to preserve as much of the layer as possible, the end goal would be to stuff it. I have an idea of what i want to stuff it with, but have yet to succeed in the "taking the onion" apart

Answer (score 4):

I once made onion bowls by slicing the onion at the point where it just starts to curve back in and soaking in water while I seperated the layers.  It worked for my purposes but I did destroy a few in the process.  I think I might have added some salt to the water they were soaking in to boost the water content of the onion, which could have affected how easily they seperated.

Comment: I agree, and I usually bake them with a bit of water in the oven until they soften, and "squeeze" them out

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much of the "bowl" you need to be intact. If you don't mind cutting the onion in half and then slicing off say about 1/2" off each end, so you have a truncate hemisphere, then you can wiggle off individual layers pretty easily.

Comment: I'd rather keep the layers intact, but I wouldn't mind losing some of the middle ones.